# Сохранение и восстановление перемещения через ObjectAnimator до и после паузы

Tags: android, объекты, android-animation, objectanimator

Дано - ObjectAnimator, imageView.

ImageView должен переместится с левого края до правого.

ObjectAnimator начинает свое действие - ImageView перемещается слева направо.

И вдруг откуда не возьмись - активити сворачивается и вызывает метод onPause/onStop - это юзер свернул окошко.

ObjectAnimator прекращает свои манипуляции над ImageView, и imageView не доходит до правого края.

А теперь задача. Как во время onPause/onStop сохранить текущее положение ImageView, а после onResume/onStart продолжит выполнение анимации с того места с которого остановился?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в методе `onPause` следует сохранить координаты х и у например в `SharedPreferences`. А в методе `onResume` запускать анимацию начиная с этих координат.

Реализация "в лоб" будет выглядеть следующим образом.

```
private ImageView imageView;
.
.
.
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putFloat("x", imageView.getX());
    editor.putFloat("y", imageView.getY());
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhX = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(TRANSLATION_X, prefs.getFloat("x",0), maxWidth);
    PropertyValuesHolder pvhY = PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(TRANSLATION_Y, prefs.getFloat("y",0), maxHeight);
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(imageView, pvhX, pvhY);
    animator.start();
}
```